# Having troubles with finding treemap algorithm code/pseudocode

Tags: python, algorithm, visualization, pseudocode, treemap

I am working on a project where I want to make the treemap algorithm but I have no idea how to begin.
Also I don't want to use `matplotlib` and `squarify`. Can you help me with pseudo code?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `matplotlib` and `squarify` packages? Along with `Pygal`, they seem to be the best Python implementations out there (obviously worse than the R ones).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a tree that is somehow annotated with percentages and that you want to display as/convert into a treemap (as in https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_Map).

I'd start with these building blocks:

- If you have a node with children `c_1`, `c_2`, ..., `c_n` with respective percentages `p_1`, `p_2`, ..., `p_n`, think about how you could subdivide a rectangle so that the resulting sub-rectangles represent the percentages.

  - One way would be to simply subdivide the rectangle horizontally or vertically wrt to the percentages.
  - Maybe it looks better if you choose the larger dimension (i.e. you subdivide horizontally or vertically depending on whether the rectangle is wider than high or vice-versa.)
- Doing the actual subdivision:

  - Start with an initial rectangle.
  - Traverse the tree (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal):
  - For each node with children, subdivide the current sub-rectangle according to the childrens' percentages.
  - As soon as you visit a child, make the subdivision of the current sub-rectangle the current sub-rectangle.
  - As soon as you finish a node, make the parent rectangle the current sub-rectangle.